# Robolectric and Instrumentation tests in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, robolectric

I want to create Robolectric tests to supplement my existing instrumentation tests. I have found [a gradle plugin](https://github.com/AndroidApps101/gradle-android-test-plugin) that purports to support a separate module with the Robolectric tests. However, when I attempt to use this plugin, I get the following error:

> Class not found: "bbct.android.test.activity.test.FilterCardsTest"

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "bbct.android.common"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        lite {
            applicationId "bbct.android"
            versionCode 15
            versionName "0.6.2"
        }
        premium {
            applicationId "bbct.android.premium"
            versionCode 14
            versionName "0.6.2"
        }
    }
    def Properties props = new Properties()
    def propFile = new File('signing.properties')
    if (propFile.canRead()) {
        props.load(new FileInputStream(propFile))

        if (props!=null && props.containsKey('STORE_FILE') && props.containsKey('STORE_PASSWORD') &&
                props.containsKey('KEY_ALIAS') && props.containsKey('KEY_PASSWORD')) {
            android.signingConfigs.release.storeFile = file(props['STORE_FILE'])
            android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = props['STORE_PASSWORD']
            android.signingConfigs.release.keyAlias = props['KEY_ALIAS']
            android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = props['KEY_PASSWORD']
        } else {
            println 'signing.properties found but some entries are missing'
            android.buildTypes.release.signingConfig = null
        }
    } else {
        println 'signing.properties not found'
        android.buildTypes.release.signingConfig = null
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.2.42'
    liteCompile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.1'
    androidTestCompile ('com.squareup:fest-android:1.0.8') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
}
```

And `FilterCardsTest`:

```
package bbct.android.test.activity.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import bbct.android.common.activity.FragmentTestActivity;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.robolectric.Robolectric;
import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner;
import org.robolectric.annotation.Config;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

@Config(manifest = "./src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class FilterCardsTest {

    @Test
    public void testSomething() throws Exception {
        Activity activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(FragmentTestActivity.class).create().get();
        assertTrue(activity != null);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Where get you the class not found exception? I'm expecting it comes when you robolectric test inside Android studio.

There may be different reason. First your test class will not be compiled when you start a test in android studio. Second Android studio doesn't know where to search for the compiled class.

For first issue just compile your test classes. For the second issue you can modify the test module iml file where you must change the path of the test-output to your needs.

Here is a full example, which will do the iml modification automatically.
https://github.com/nenick/android-gradle-template

And here details how you can force android studio to compile your test classes 
https://github.com/nenick/android-gradle-template/wiki/Tests-in-Android-Studio---IntellJ

Comment: Yes, I get the exception when I try to run the Robolectric tests in Android Studio.